# prolog cant compile foreign module

Tags: swi-prolog

I am trying to build a foreign module for prolog.

I already succeed under Unix, but I can't do it under Windows. I tried the MinGW's `g++` command and the `swipl-ld.exe`, provided by SWI Prolog.

Here are the commands I tried :`

- `g++ -I "C:\Program Files\swipl\include" -o test test.cpp`
- `swipl-ld -o test test.cpp`

Both yeld the same `undefined reference to 'PL_some_function'`, several times.

Here is my `test.cpp` :

```
#include <SWI-cpp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

PREDICATE(hello, 1)
{ cout << "Hello " << (char *)A1 << endl;

    return TRUE;
}
```

I suppose it's an import problem, but I have no idea where the files are nor how I have to do it.

EDIT: examples of `PL_some_function`:

```
test.obj:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN7PlTermvC1Ei[__ZN7PlTermvC1Ei]+0x10): undefined reference to `PL_new_term_refs'

test.obj:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN11PlExceptionC2Ev[__ZN11PlExceptionC2Ev]+0x1b): undefined reference to `PL_exception'

test.obj:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN11PlExceptionC2Ev[__ZN11PlExceptionC2Ev]+0x3a): undefined reference to `PL_fatal_error'
```

Comment: What is `pl_somefunction`? Perhaps you are missing a library on your Windows machine?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Edited.